# How to write a generalized multi level linked list?

Tags: c

A linked list of type

```
1- 3- 4 - ... -10
|  |  | ...     |
10 20 3 ...     40
.  .  .          .
.  .  .          .
```

I have written 2 structures

```
struct flat{
    int data;
    struct flat *next;
    struct flat *down;
};

struct flat1{
    int data;
    struct flat1 *next;
};
```

One for horizontal list and one for the vertical ones.But while proceeding to creation of linked list came to know that incompatible assignments from flat to flat1 are there.

How to write generalized code in a single structure?

Comment: why would you assign from flat to flat1? each has its own purpose. Either way - you could write a simple planar graph node with right and down connections (or any other ones) and simply keep the unused ones disconnected.

Comment: in theory you coud use a union of either a struct with two pointers or a struct with one pointer after the data, but it seems to me that it would be easier to assign only down in the lists that go down

Comment: I would suggest only one struct.   Then declare a 'head' pointer: struct flat1 ** head = NULL;   Then allocate memory(as needed) for the array of pointers:  head = malloc( x * sizeof(struct flat1 *) );   After that, each linked list of structs can be started by: head[x] = malloc(sizeof(struct flat1), etc

Comment: It can always have a NULL as one of the fields...